# Unable to change the Background of frame

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from datetime import datetime

import MySQLdb


conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', database = 'school_mana', user = 'root', password = 'Kushal@2006',charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()


class Man_em1():
    def __init__(self, frame_name):
        self.frame_name = frame_name

        self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_name, height = 700, width = 1350, labelanchor = tk.N, font = 'Arial 50', bg = 'black')

        self.note1 = ttk.Notebook(self.frame_name)
        self.note1.add(self.f3, text = 'EDIT')

        self.note1.place(x = 0, y = 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Man_em1:
    def __init__(self, frame_name):
        self.frame_name = frame_name

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(frame_name)
        self.notebook.pack()

        self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.notebook, height=700, width=1350, bg="black")
        self.notebook.add(self.f3, text="EDIT")


root = tk.Tk()
obj = Man_em1(root)
```

When you are trying to add a frame to a `ttk.Notebook`, the frame's master must be the notebook instance. So `self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_name, ...)` => `self.f3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.notebook, ...)`